# Как применить к каждой RadioButton один и тот же метод, не прописывая отдельно для каждой кнопки?

Tags: java, android, radiobutton

Посоветуйте пожалуйста, не могу разобраться. Как применить к каждой `RadioButton` из `RadioGroup rgChoice` следующий метод, не прописывая для каждой кнопки отдельно? Я их объединял в `ArrayList<RadioButton>`, но потом у меня есть другая куча кнопок их там больше двадцати, все их отдельно добавлять долго. Должен же быть нормальный способ...

```
    RadioGroup rgChoice = findViewById(R.id.rg_choice);

       RadioButton rbDenial, rbSomeChoice, rbGreaterChoise, rbDiscernment;

public void checkRepres(String json, CompoundButton btnView, ArrayList<String> list) {
        if (json.contains(btnView.getText().toString())) {
            btnView.setChecked(true);
            list.add(btnView.getText().toString());
        }
    }
```

PS то же самое интересует и для ChipGroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вешайте "слушатель" на группу, а не на каждую кнопку.

```
RadioGroup rg = findViewById( R.id.rg );
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged( RadioGroup radioGroup, int id ){
                RadioButton radioButton = radioGroup.findViewById(id);
                // делайте здесь, что вам нужно
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Указать в xml свойство для каждой Radiobutton android:onClick="checkRepres"